# saving the shuffled images in a batch to disk with original filename

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a dataset in a single dir, that I wish to split into training and validation set, then save all of images of each set to a different dir

I'm trying to do this by using the tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory() and tf.keras.preprocessing.image.save_img() functions, and the  tf.data.Dataset.file_paths attribute

code looks something like this:

```
train_dataset = image_dataset_from_directory(PATH_DS,
                                             shuffle=True,
                                             labels='inferred', 
                                             label_mode='categorical',
                                             class_names=class_names,
                                             batch_size=1,
                                             image_size=[1080, 1920],
                                             validation_split=0.15,
                                             subset="training",
                                             seed=456)
validation_dataset = image_dataset_from_directory(PATH_DS,
                                             shuffle=True,
                                             labels='inferred', 
                                             label_mode='categorical',
                                             class_names=class_names,
                                             batch_size=1,
                                             image_size=[1080, 1920],
                                             validation_split=0.15,
                                             subset="validation",
                                             seed=456)

filepaths_val = validation_dataset.file_paths
filepaths_train = train_dataset.file_paths

for idx, (batch, filepath) in enumerate(zip(train_dataset.as_numpy_iterator(), train_dataset.file_paths)):
    images, labels = batch

    tf.keras.preprocessing.image.save_img(os.path.join(PATH_WD, f"test/train/{class_names[np.argmax(labels[0])]}/{os.path.basename(filepath)}"), images[0], "channels_last", "png")
```

I need to have the images shuffled because they have filenames such that a alphanumerical sort would result in data leakage between the sets

The problem I am running into seems to be that the dataset iterator has random initialization. The filepaths object is just a list that I can slice, and I've already verified that each seed always returns the same file paths.

However, calling the dataset always returns a different element. I've tried the Dataset.unbatch() method, as_numpy_iterator(), etc. Every time I call the iterator for the first time, it returns a different element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved this by using a far simpler and faster approach

since I already have the list of images in each split of the dataset, I can simply use shutil to copy or move the items.

This approach made some other things I wanted to do with the images more difficult, but solvable